# About an interpretation of implication

Tags: logic, paradox

Could the ' If P then Q ' be interpreted as 'If  P is assumed to be true then Q is true '?  This could explain why a false proposition implies any proposition , according to Raymond Smullyan. If P is a false proposition and  P is assumed to be true ( when it is actually false) this introduces a paradox from which any proposition can be implied.

Comment: Nothing is 'proven'. Consider this: if x>5, then x>3. Suppose we're given that x<5. Is x>3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notions to be distinguished here: [logical consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Syntactic_consequence) (⊢) vs [material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (→), each of which, in classical logic, has the unusual property of [explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), which we can summarize as:

> **⊢–Explosion.** {S,¬S} ⊢ Q, for any Q.
>
> **→–Explosion.** Under assignment v(S) = ⊥: S → Q, for any Q.

<kbd>1</kbd> The →–Explosion follows simply from the definition of → in terms of disjunction and negation:

> (φ → ψ) =<sub>df</sub> (¬φ ∨ ψ),

because whenever the truth-assignment v is such that v(φ) = ⊥, then φ ∨ ψ follows, for any ψ. Proof theoretically, whenever ¬φ is proved, you can ∨-introduce ¬φ ∨ ψ where ψ can be any sentence whatsoever. The reason why the classical consequence explodes is a little more interesting.

<kbd>2</kbd> According to the usual [Tarskian interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) of logical consequence:

> *Logical Consequence.* Γ ⊢ φ is true iff it is impossible to make all ψ ∈ Γ true and φ false.

Whenever you have a sentence S ∈ Γ s.t. ¬S is also in Γ, you have the sentence (S ∧ ¬S) ∈ Γ. Consider an arbitrary sentence Q; is Q a logical consequence of Γ, given that Γ contains such an inconsistent conjunction? Let's appeal to the definition above:

> {S, ¬S,...,S<sub>n</sub>} ⊢ Q is true iff it is impossible to make all of S, ¬S,...,S<sub>n</sub> true and Q false.

Since S and ¬S are inconsistent they cannot both be made true, therefore, whatever else may be contained in Γ and whatever Q may be, it follows that {S, ¬S,...,S<sub>n</sub>} ⊢ Q. It is an immediate byproduct of the classical definition of consequence.

There are, of course, many non-explosive logics, such as Belnap and Anderson's [relevance logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/#Sem) where from a contradiction an arbitrary Q isn't allowed to follow because implication has to meet special 'relevance' requirements. Look at that last SEP article for the details on how exactly that works. Most relevantly, there are many [paraconsistent logics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/) specifically created to handle this so-called 'paradox' of material implication. Worth checking out.

Comment: @user128932 - Pefect answer ! I like to add only one comment. The two notion are **very** different (as explained by Hunan) : The conditional (or material implication (→)) is a *connective* "inside" the language, logical consequence (⊢) is a relation between sentences of the language (thus, defined "outside" it). Their "independence" can be simply "viewed" in this way: we can have e.g.propositional languages without the → connective and the definition of consequence is the same. **But** there is a strong link between the two. 1/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You're too kind. Thanks for your comments. In the second one, is there a typo in the very last sequent (the one you called 'mp')?

Comment: One of the "basic" rules of inference is modus ponens and it exploit the truth-functional characteristics of (→) to licence us to infer ψ from φ and (φ→ψ). In other way, mp says that : (φ→ψ), φ ⊢ ψ .